# Implicit Function Theorem [Finding $\frac{du}{dx}$]

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations

In the link: http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~svanstri/Files/multivariable-calculus.pdf on the very last slide, I am confused on on why they are doing the jacobian matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{du}{dx} \\ \frac{dv}{dx}\end{pmatrix}$. Can someone explain this part?

Answer (score 0):

It's because they were solving a system of equations with $\frac{du}{dx}$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ as the unknowns. A way of solving a system of linear equations is by elementary row operations.